# How Can I assign a sequence value to a sqlite field when the field UID value is NULL

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment, manual, unique-key

How I can assign a sequence value to a field "UID" which is NUll in existing sqlite table, for example

```
table: FOO  
name    UID
A   1
B   2
C   100
D   NULL
E   NULL
F   NULL
```

what I want is

```
table: FOO  
name    UID
A   1
B   2
C   100
D   101
E   102
F   103
```

Can some body help?
I want to seek an alternative for using autoincrement on my own reason...

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Register a function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that returns the number of times it's called, and then do

```
UPDATE FOO SET UID = 100 + increment() WHERE UID IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks, should increment() be a C function,or can it be python function? Or, can SQL language such as SELECT count(*) from FOO works instead of increment() ?